# Hudson plugin warning

Tags: java, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

I see the message in hudson console

```
WARNING: Faild to load hudson.plugins.groovy.GroovyTokenMacro
java.lang.HoClassDefFoundError:    org/jenkinsci/plugin/tokenmacro/DataBoundTokenMacro .....
```

I have re downloaded  .hdi file and got same warning. I am not sure that it was before.

How can I solve it? My hudson is in unsecured mode.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you prefer? c# assembler? Is it hudson(jencins) for php?

Comment: I dont understand yours -1 vote, please explain, thanks!